# 2D boolean mask in numpy yields different results (mask ordering vs. original indices)

Tags: python, numpy

I am playing around with different indexing methods. I have the following working example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(321,321)
a = range(0, 300)
b = range(1, 301)
mask = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
# a and b are lists 
mask[a, b] = True
assert x[a, b].shape == x[mask].shape  # passes
assert np.isclose(np.sum(x[mask]), np.sum(x[a, b]))  # passes
assert np.allclose(x[mask], x[a, b])  # fails sometimes
```

When I try it with a different `x` for a project, the last assertion fails. Here is a failing case:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(431,431)
a = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 11, 2]

mask = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
# a and b are lists 
mask[a, b] = True
assert x[a, b].shape == x[mask].shape  # passes
assert np.isclose(np.sum(x[mask]), np.sum(x[a, b]))  # passes
assert np.allclose(x[mask], x[a, b])  # fails
```

Can anyone explain why this error occurs? I assume it's because mask is indexing into x differently from (a,b), but not sure how.

I want to do this because I'd like to easily get `x[~mask]`

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Could be because x has Fortran ordering?

Comment: Do you here change the `mask`? Since right now `x[mask]` will be an empty array.

Comment: I updated the question to be more precise.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` actually initialized like that in the failing case? Please post something that runs and reproduces the error when run.

Comment: I added an explicit failing case

Comment: The order of elements in `x[mask]` and `x[a,b]` are different.  With only 8 elements you can easily print and compare them.  No need to depend on tests that hide the details.  You could also see the difference by comparing `np.where(mask)` and `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example lies in how you defined `a` and `b`. If you were to print out `x[a, b]` and `x[mask]` you would notice that the 5th and 6th elements on `x[a, b]` would be switched with the 5th and 6th values in `x[mask]`. The reason for this is that you set every value in `mask` to True using `a` and `b` to index so order didn't matter but you're using `a` and `b` to index x in your assertion so order matters there. When you do your index, numpy is taking each value from `a` to get the appropriate row from your matrix and using the value in the same index on `b` to index into that row. To illustrate using a 3x8 array:

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
b = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7]

x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

x[a, b] = [2, 9, 11, 13, 20, 18, 24]
mask[a, b] = [2, 9, 11, 13, 18, 20, 24]
```

A good way to fix this would be to first define `a` and `b` as a list of tuples, sort them on their "a-value" first and then on their "b-value" and use them from there. That way you can guarantee the order.

Answer (score 1):

As @hpaulj mentioned the order of the arrays is different:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.rand(431,431)
a = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 11, 2]

mask = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
# a and b are lists
mask[a, b] = True

print(x[mask])
print(x[a, b])
```

**Output**

```
[0.95071431 0.76151063 0.10112268 0.70096913 0.44076275 0.55964033
 0.40873417 0.20015024]
[0.95071431 0.76151063 0.10112268 0.70096913 0.55964033 0.44076275
 0.40873417 0.20015024]
```

The reason is that the mask returns in in row-major (C-style) order (see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)) and as for [multidimensional indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays):

> if the index arrays have a matching shape, and there is an index array
>   for each dimension of the array being indexed, the resultant array has
>   the same shape as the index arrays, and the values correspond to the
>   index set for each position in the index arrays.

In your case the order from the multidimensional indexing is:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 11), (3, 2)]
```

and from the mask is:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 11), (3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`x[a, b]` selects elements from `x` in the order given by `a` and `b`. `x[a[i], b[i]]` will come before `x[a[i+1], b[i+1]]` in the result.

`x[mask]` selects elements in the order given by iterating over `mask` in row-major order to find `True` cells. This is only the same order as `x[a, b]` if `zip(a, b)` is already lexicographically sorted.

In your failing example, `2, 3` comes before `2, 1` in `a` and `b`, but iterating over `mask` in row-major order will find the `True` at `2, 1` before `2, 3`. Thus, `x[mask]` has `x[2, 1]` before `x[2, 3]`, while `x[a, b]` has those elements the other way around.